# Do you have to open the Mailbox Mac App for it to return emails to your inbox?

Tags: macos, mailbox

Mailbox provides a method to delay your emails until later. After a time, the emails will re-appear in the inbox allowing you to deal with it then.

Do you need to have Mailbox open in order for these emails to be brought back into your inbox?

Comment: @Ramhound: It is now a Mac Desktop app too!

Comment: Update your question to indicate that